# Global name not defined when calling function as __init__() variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I have a Python file which looks something like this:

```
imports

def install_tests(version):
    ...

class Test(TestConfig):
    def __init__(self,
                 parameters)
        super(Test, self).__init__(parameters=parameters)
        self.client = install_tests(version)
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'install_tests' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. `install_tests` is outside of the class so it is `global` and I think that the fact I've got a function there suggests it is defined. Have I missed anything?

Comment: I think you cannot define a function outside a class. That's the point of oriented-object programming. Each function (method) is attached to a class.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a typo, but without the actual code and the actual traceback it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Maxouille No no no no no. This is python; you don't need classes. If you want a function, you write a function. If you want a method, you write a class with a method. `install_tests` certainly doesn't look like a method.

Comment: @Aran-Fey okay seems logic... :p

Comment: Can you please edit your question including some missing part of your code (like, how are you instantiating your class, what install_tests does, how you handle "version" param from within your class, etc.). I tried a simplified version of your code and install_tests is working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to affect `install_tests` function to a variable inside your class.

```
def install_tests(version):
    print "install_tests"

class Test(TestConfig):
    myMethod = install_tests
    def __init__(self,
                 parameters)
        super(Test, self).__init__(parameters=parameters)      
        self.client = myMethod(version)
```

Hope it helps!